# Get a value from instance of a class

Tags: python, class, methods, return

```
    class Jokes:
    def __init__(self, *joke):
        self.joke_list = []
        self.used_joke_list = []
        self.joke = joke
        if self.joke not in self.joke_list and self.joke not in self.used_joke_list:
            self.add_Joke(joke)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} \n {}".format(self.joke.split("...")[0], self.joke.split("...")[1])

    def show_Joke(self):
        if len(self.joke_list) > 0:
            randjoke = rand.randint(0,len(self.joke_list) - 1)
            self.cur_joke = self.joke_list[randjoke]
            self.used_joke_list.append(self.cur_joke)
            self.joke_list.remove(self.cur_joke)
            return str(self.cur_joke)

        elif len(self.joke_list) == 0:
            for joke in self.used_joke_list:
                self.joke_list.append(joke)
                self.used_joke_list.remove(joke)
                self.show_Joke()
    def add_Joke(self, joke):
        #joke = input("What's you joke? /n")
        self.joke_list.append(joke)

joke1 = Jokes("Which bear is the most condescending? A pan-duh!")
joke2 = Jokes("We're afraid for this calendar... It's days are numbered")
joke3 = Jokes("6:30 is the best time on a clock... Hands down")
joke4 = Jokes("A detective was rushed to the ER... He accidentally poked his private eye")
joke5 = Jokes("A friend of mine collects blunt pencils... Personally, I find his hobby a bit pointless")
print(Jokes.show_Joke)
```

I'm trying to create a program that shows a random bad dad joke, allows the user to add new jokes, and to show a random joke

I'm using a list to store new and used jokes to prevent repeats and in this example, I've added a few jokes. Whenever I try to call the show joke method though, all I get is <function Jokes.show_Joke at 0x000002478B02A0E0>. If I add () at the end of the line (print(Jokes.show_joke()), I get an error about parameters. I don't want to call a specific instance of the class, I want it to be randomized.

How do I get it to return the joke so I can show it on a label? (Also using tkinter for the gui, but that parts going fine)

Comment: Hey! Your implementation could work only if your class was a Singleton and calling `Jokes().show_Joke()`. But I'm not sure that this is the best way of solving your problem, there is a lots of more easier solutions (like creating a simple instance and then add it and finally show it)

Comment: It seems like you're creating a joke object for each individual joke. What I think you want to be doing is creating one joke object and adding many jokes to that one object. Of course you'll need to add a function to insert more jokes into the list

Comment: To call a function/method you have to add parentheses. But your task is doomed anyway since you freely mix class attributes and instance attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're confused about whether an instance of the `Jokes` class represents a single joke or a collection of jokes.  I suggest making it be a collection of jokes, meaning that you'd create
a *single* `Jokes` object and add a bunch of jokes to it, rather than creating one `Jokes` object per joke:

```
import random

class Jokes:
    def __init__(self, *jokes):
        self.new_jokes = []
        self.used_jokes = set()
        self.add_jokes(*jokes)

    def add_jokes(self, *jokes):
        self.new_jokes.extend(jokes)
        random.shuffle(self.new_jokes)

    def __str__(self):
        return " ... ".join(self.new_jokes)

    def show_joke(self):
        if not self.new_jokes:
            # recycle all the old jokes
            self.new_jokes = list(self.used_jokes)
            random.shuffle(self.new_jokes)
            self.used_jokes.clear()

        joke = self.new_jokes.pop()
        self.used_jokes.add(joke)
        return joke

jokes = Jokes(
    "Which bear is the most condescending? A pan-duh!",
    "We're afraid for this calendar... It's days are numbered",
    "6:30 is the best time on a clock... Hands down",
    "A detective was rushed to the ER... He accidentally poked his private eye",
    "A friend of mine collects blunt pencils... Personally, I find his hobby a bit pointless",
)
print(jokes.show_joke())
```

Note that `show_joke` is an instance method (it takes `self` as a parameter, since that's how it knows where to find `self.new_jokes` and `self.used_jokes`), so you call it on the `jokes` instance, not the `Jokes` class.

Comment: I'm totally confused with classes lol Thank you for the feedback on the situation. I was trying to make a single joke object with all the jokes stored to it like you mentioned. I'll give this a shot, thank you again!

I noticed you changed a few things like self.used_jokes = set()
Why would you do that as opposed to creating another empty string? And, will that still work if we're randomizing the jokes that appear from the new_jokes list?